# Just simple file syncing for ubuntu

Tags: server, kubuntu, ftp, dropbox, proftpd

I'm just a new guy with Ubuntu VPS. I've a simple purpose to solve.

I've a gameserver to manage, I've some friends that develop files with me.

Is there any way I can give them some files, folders to access? So that they can do their development in their own folder?

Like edit, download, upload in their own folder?

I've tried following things:
GADMIN-PROFTPD
Dropbox
vsftpd
openssh
chroot
Pureadmin

And nothing of those haven't worked for me. If you can help me with this, please do. Try to be noob friendly if you can... thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I can think of is to use Google Drive. The best GDrive client I've found for Ubuntu is Insync. Just log in, set up your syncronized files and/or folders, and everything works like a charm.

https://www.insynchq.com/

It is a $20 one-time, but you get a free 15-day trial, so it's plenty of time to see if it works for you.

Comment: I tried dropbox, I think we need to move files to the dropbox folder to get synced but my problem is, I have files somewhere else than that dropbox folder.

Comment: The InSync program allows you to sync files and folders outside the synced folder. See this howto: https://support.insynchq.com/t/how-to-sync-folders-outside-of-the-insync-folder/33